# How to print data regarding to class chosen (common dataset for 2 classes)?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I wrote two classes. The second one inherits from the first one. They all base on common dataset which have all data needed by two classes (business cards collection).

Question: Is it possible to print all names with the parameters limited by one or another class? For example `print(*BusinessContact, sep='\n')` - should print all names (Andrew and Tom) - with all parameters or `print(*BaseContact, sep='\n')` - all names but without company info as BaseContact includes?

Example:

```
class BaseContact:
  def __init__(self, first_name, second_name):
       self.first_name = first_name
       self.second_name = second_name

  def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.first_name} {self.second_name}'

class BusinessContact(BaseContact):
  def __init__(self, company,  *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.company = company

  def __str__(self):
      return f' {self.company} {self.first_name} {self.second_name}'

andrew_witt = [?](first_name="Andrew", second_name="Witt", company="Some sides")
tom_smith = [?](first_name="Tom", second_name="Smith", company="Reality")


[?] = [andrew_witt, tom_smith]

by_first_name = sorted([?], key=lambda BaseContact: BaseContact.first_name)
```

Comment: sounds like you want a database ...

Comment: What do you expect to happen if someone prints a ``BaseContact`` as a ``BusinessContact``?

Comment: Can you please clarify? If someone prints BaseContact it should print first and second name if someone prints BusinessContact it should print first, second name and company.

Comment: Since a ``BaseContact`` does not have a company, what do you expect to happen if someone prints a ``BaseContact`` (provides ``first_name``, ``second_name``) as a ``BusinessContact`` (requires ``first_name``, ``second_name``, **``company``**)?

Comment: I don't see in your code where you are causing a call to `__str__()`.  Do you print `by_first_name`?

Comment: Cargo23 I didn't call it becouse I dont' know how should I do it.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, the point is I don't want to provide parameters. I just want to get the info from the lines already written. In this example Andrew and Tom's position. Exctract 2 or 3 data according to class chosen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class' `__str__` method can be explicitly called. In case of compatible subclasses, this allows to call the baseclass' `__str__` on a subclass instance.

```
# subclass instance
andrew_witt = BusinessContact(first_name="Andrew", second_name="Witt", company="Some sides")
# current class __str__
print(andrew_witt)                          #  Some sides Andrew Witt
# explicit subclass __str__
print(BusinessContact.__str__(andrew_witt)) #  Some sides Andrew Witt
# explicit baseclass __str__
print(BaseContact.__str__(andrew_witt))     # Andrew Witt
```

To format an entire list, the desired method can be mapped on each element using `map` or a comprehension.

```
people = [
    BusinessContact(first_name="Andrew", second_name="Witt", company="Some sides"),
    BusinessContact(first_name="Tom", second_name="Smith", company="Reality"),
]
print(*map(BaseContact.__str__, people), sep='\n')
# Andrew Witt
# Tom Smith
```

Comment: MisterMiyagi. It works fine on a single element, but how to make it works on all elements (in this example Andrew and Tom in one print command)?

Comment: @MaciekŁubocki I've added an example of mapping the method onto a list of contacts.